# Can I use the socket io library on the client side and a completely different websocket library on the server side?

Tags: websocket

I am starting with websockets.

I've come across a bit of a puzzle in my head and I hope someone will be able to answer this question for me

Can I use the socket.io library on the client side and a completely different websocket library on the server side?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting front-end native websocket client to Node.js Socket.io server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019156/connecting-front-end-native-websocket-client-to-node-js-socket-io-server)